# jQuery: Add a title attribute to an element and insert text from following element

Tags: jquery, image, attributes, title

I'm not even sure if this is possible but let's have a go.

I have this HTML being dynamically generated for each image:

```
<a href="image.jpg" class="thickbox">
    <img src="thumb.jpg" title="This is the title" alt="" />
</a>
```

Somehow I need to take the title attribute from thumb.jpg and copy it to the surrounding anchor, which would give this result:

```
<a href="image.jpg" class="thickbox" title="This is the title" alt="">
    <img src="thumb.jpg" title="This is the title" alt="" />
</a>
```

I'd be happy if this could be achieved with jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('a.thickbox img').each(function(key,$elem){
    $(this).parent().attr('title',$(this).attr('title'));
});
```

Loop using each, if you have more than one image. Else use the line in the function and replace `$(this)` by `$('a.thickbox img')`.

Comment: Worked perfectly. And kudos for the fast response!

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a function to [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) (or [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)) and write something like:

```
$("a.thickbox").attr("title", function() {
    return $(this).find("img").attr("title");
});
```

(I used `attr()` in the code above to emphasize the fact we're creating an HTML attribute. `prop()`, which creates or updates DOM properties, would give the same results).

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the thumbnails using the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and, for those with an `<a>` parent, set the parent title to the img's title.

```
$("img[src='thumb.jpg']").each( function() {
    $(this).parent('a.thickbox').attr('title', this.title);
});
```